# Unzipping a file in asp.net mvc3 using .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

i need to upload a zip file, click a button and unzip it in the same folder and give this folder the same name. I have NO idea where to start, I have the upload part sofar:
my view:

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   { %>                                       

       <%: Html.ZincValidationSummary() %>  
       <%: Html.ZincValidationErrors() %>           

       <div class="section _100">
         <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)%>                               
         <div>
           <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { maxlength = "100" })%>     
           <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)%> 
         </div>
       </div>   

       <div class="section _100">           
         <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScormPackageFile) %>
         <div>
           <br />
           <input type="file" id="ScormPackageFile" name="ScormPackageFile" />
           <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScormPackageFile)%>
           <br />
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
         <div class="actions-right">
           <input type="submit" value="<%: Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Save) %>" class="submit_button" />
         </div>
       </div>  
  <% } %>
```

in the controller: this is where i dont know what to do:

```
 HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Upload(ScormUploadViewModel model)
 {
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (model.ScormPackageFile != null)
    {
      string extractDir = "c:\\TSFPreview\\Zinc\\Web\\Project\\ScormPackages";
      //I should get the above dir from the uploaded file's directory because the                   
        unziped folder will be in the same folder 


    }
    var smallImageUrl = MediaStorageService.UploadFromStream(Zinc.Media.MediaType.Attribute, model.ScormPackageFile.FileName, model.ScormPackageFile.ContentType, model.ScormPackageFile.InputStream);
      //group.SmallImageUrl = smallImageUrl;
   }
   return View(model);
 }
```

then my viewmodel:

```
public class ScormUploadViewModel
{
  [LocalizedRequired]
  [DataType(DataType.Text)]
  [LocalizedDisplayName(Resources.Global.Title.Name)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("Upload a scorm package")]
  public HttpPostedFileBase ScormPackageFile { get; set; }
}
```

thanks I do not know what other tags i should add for now i just added the asp.net mvc 3 tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GZipStream, it's one of the built-in zip support in the framework, there's an example on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

Comment: i had a look but i only have one file i want to unzip and in this zip file is alot of other files. I dont need to do using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName) I just need to create a folder with the same name as the zip file without the .zip extension. so what line there actually does the unzipping?

Comment: also in my viewmodel of what type must my ScormPackageFile be? string, FileInfo or HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_7301924_unzip-file-c_.html try this link bt is is not an MVC bt u will modify the code in to MVC

Comment: ai ive been through that code and still need to know of what type must my file be in my viewmodel?? then I am one step further please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use some library for uzipping. For example https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/